# How does local() differ from other approaches to closure in R?

Tags: r, closures, local, static-variables

Yesterday I learned from Bill Venables how local() can help create static functions and variables, e.g.,

```
example <- local({
  hidden.x <- "You can't see me!"
  hidden.fn <- function(){
    cat("\"hidden.fn()\"")
  }
  function(){
    cat("You can see and call example()\n")
    cat("but you can't see hidden.x\n")
    cat("and you can't call ")
    hidden.fn()
    cat("\n")
  }
})
```

which behaves as follows from the command prompt:

```
> ls()
[1] "example"
> example()
You can see and call example()
but you can't see hidden.x
and you can't call "hidden.fn()"
> hidden.x                 
Error: object 'hidden.x' not found
> hidden.fn()
Error: could not find function "hidden.fn"
```

I've seen this kind of thing discussed in [Static Variables in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1088639/1014385) where a different approach was employed.

What the pros and cons of these two methods?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Encapsulation**

The advantage of this style of programming is that the hidden objects won't likely be overwritten by anything else so you can be more confident that they contain what you think.    They won't be used by mistake since they can't readily be accessed.  In the linked-to post in the question there is a global variable, `count`, which could be accessed and overwritten from anywhere so if we are debugging code and looking at `count` and see its changed we cannnot really be sure what part of the code has changed it.  In contrast, in the example code of the question we have greater assurance that no other part of the code is involved.

Note that we actually can access the hidden function although its not that easy:

```
# run hidden.fn
environment(example)$hidden.fn()
```

**Object Oriented Programming**

Also note that this is very close to object oriented programming where `example` and `hidden.fn` are methods and `hidden.x` is a property.  We could do it like this to make it explicit:

```
library(proto)
p <- proto(x = "x", 
  fn = function(.) cat(' "fn()"\n '),
  example = function(.) .$fn()
)
p$example() # prints "fn()"
```

proto does not hide `x` and `fn` but its not that easy to access them by mistake since you must use `p$x` and `p$fn()` to access them which is not really that different than being able to write `e <- environment(example); e$hidden.fn()`

EDIT:

The object oriented approach does add the possibility of inheritance, e.g. one could define a child of `p` which acts like `p` except that it overrides `fn`.

```
ch <- p$proto(fn = function(.) cat("Hello from ch\n")) # child
ch$example() # prints: Hello from ch
```

Answer (score 6):

`local()` can implement a singleton pattern -- e.g., the `snow` package uses this to track the single Rmpi instance that the user might create.

```
getMPIcluster <- NULL
setMPIcluster <- NULL
local({
    cl <- NULL
    getMPIcluster <<- function() cl
    setMPIcluster <<- function(new) cl <<- new
})
```

`local()` might also be used to manage memory in a script, e.g., allocating large intermediate objects required to create a final object on the last line of the clause. The large intermediate objects are available for garbage collection when `local` returns.

Using a function to create a closure is a factory pattern -- the [bank account](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Scope) example in the Introduction To R documentation, where each time `open.account` is invoked, a new account is created.

As @otsaw mentions, memoization might be implemented using local, e.g., to cache web sites in a crawler

```
library(XML)
crawler <- local({
    seen <- new.env(parent=emptyenv())
    .do_crawl <- function(url, base, pattern) {
        if (!exists(url, seen)) {
            message(url)
            xml <- htmlTreeParse(url, useInternal=TRUE)
            hrefs <- unlist(getNodeSet(xml, "//a/@href"))
            urls <-
                sprintf("%s%s", base, grep(pattern, hrefs, value=TRUE))
            seen[[url]] <- length(urls)
            for (url in urls)
                .do_crawl(url, base, pattern)
        }
    }
    .do_report <- function(url) {
        urls <- as.list(seen)
        data.frame(Url=names(urls), Links=unlist(unname(urls)),
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    }
    list(crawl=function(base, pattern="^/.*html$") {
        .do_crawl(base, base, pattern)
    }, report=.do_report)
})

crawler$crawl(favorite_url)
dim(crawler$report())
```

(the usual example of memoization, Fibonacci numbers, is not satisfying -- the range of numbers that don't overflow R's numeric representation is small , so one would probably use a look-up table of efficiently pre-calculated values). Interesting how crawler here is a singleton; could as easily have followed a factory pattern, so one crawler per base URL.

Comment: Another pattern that `local` makes convenient is memoization. There's an example somewhere in The R Inferno.

Comment: Your thought about crawler being a singleton is interesting because an alternative to local is to immediately evaluate an anonymous function with no arguments - a factory pattern might use a closure over the base url.