# R equivalent of Matlab's 'persistent'

Tags: r, matlab, variables, persistent

Say I have a `matlab` function:

```
function y = myfunc(x)
    persistent a
    a = x*10
    ...
```

What is the equivalent statement in `R` for the `persistent a` statement? `<<-` or `assign()`?

Comment: The answer depends on what persistent exactly does in matlab.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262485/options-for-caching-memoization-hashing-in-r

Comment: Matlab's persistent keyword: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/persistent.html

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088639/static-variables-in-r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
f <- local({ x<-NULL; function(y) {
   if (is.null(x)) { # or perhaps !missing(y)
      x <<- y+1
   }

   x
}})

f(3) # First time, x gets assigned
#[1] 4
f()  # Second time, old value is used
#[1] 4
```

What happens is that `local` creates a new environment around the `x<-NULL` and the function declaration. So inside the function, it can get to the `x` variable and assign to it using `<<-`.

You can find the environment for a function like this:

```
e <- environment(f)
ls(e) # "x"
```

Comment: That's nice, thanks.  One question though... The matlab help reads "They differ from global variables in that persistent variables are known only to the function in which they are declared. This prevents persistent variables from being changed by other functions or from the MATLAB command line."  Is your solution consistent with that statement?

Comment: @AndyBarbour Mostly it is. Unless you directly access it like Tommy did. Then you could change it like `e$x = 10`.

Comment: @AndyBarbour - Well almost EVERYTHING in R can be changed if you put some effort into it ;-). Nobody can change the value by mistake though. So in that respect it is consistent with the MATLAB statement.

Comment: I actually prefer the R flexibility here, though, since like you point out you still can't do it by mistake.

Comment: Thank you all.  Very insightful.

Comment: This function would be banned at `CRAN` because it modifies the global environment.  Just be warned :-)