# Proper way to have two functions access a single function's environment?

Tags: r, scope

Based on the answer provided in[1088639](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088639/static-variables-in-r), I set up a pair of functions which both access the same sub-function's environment.   This example works, but I wanted to see if I'd missed some cleaner way to "connect" both top-level functions to the internal environment.

( Back story: I wanted to write a pair of complementary functions which shared a variable, e.g. "count" in this example, **and** meet CRAN package requirements which do not allow functions to modify the global environment. )

```
static.f <- function() {
    count <- 0
    f <- function(x) {
        count <<- count + 1
        return( list(mean=mean(x), count=count) )
    }
    return( f )
}

#  make sure not to delete this command, even tho' it's not
# creating a function.
f1 <- static.f()

statfoo <- function(x){
    tmp<-f1(x)
    tmp<- list(tmp,plus=2)
    return(tmp)
}
statbar <- function(x){
    tmp<-f1(x)
    tmp<- list(tmp,minus=3)
    return(tmp)
}
```

Sample output:

```
> statfoo(5)
[[1]]
[[1]]$mean
[1] 5

[[1]]$count
[1] 1

$plus
[1] 2

Rgames> statfoo(5)
[[1]]
[[1]]$mean
[1] 5

[[1]]$count
[1] 2

$plus
[1] 2

> statbar(4)
[[1]]
[[1]]$mean
[1] 4

[[1]]$count
[1] 3

$minus
[1] 3

> statfoo(5)
[[1]]
[[1]]$mean
[1] 5

[[1]]$count
[1] 4

$plus
[1] 2
```

Comment: I think all the posted answers are good.  I selected Flick's because it doesn't require an extra package (`proto`)  and it doesn't require either a `func$part` construct or a configuration command (`environment(f1) <- environment(f2) <- list2env(list(count=0))`) as the otherwise excellent answer from Brodie does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get rid of the factory functions, and more explicitly use environments. A solution like this would work as well

```
.env<-(function() {
    count <- 0
    f <- function(x)  {
        count <<- count + 1
        return( list(mean=mean(x), count=count))
    }   
    return(environment())
})()



statfoo <- function(x){
    list(.env$f(x),plus=2)
}
statbar <- function(x){
    list(.env$f(x),minus=3)
}
```

The `.env` variable is created by immediately executing an anonymous function to get its environment. We then extract the function from the environment itself to modify its values.

Answer (score 5):

A cleaner method would be to use an object oriented approach. There is already an answer using reference classes.

A typical object oriented approach with classes would create a class and then create a singleton object, i.e. a single object of that class.   Of course it is a bit wasteful to create a class only to create one object from it so here we provide a proto example.  (Creating a function to enclose `count` and the function doing the real work has a similar problem -- you create an enclosing function only to run it once.)  The proto model allows one to create an object directly bypassing the need to create a class only to use it once.  Here `foobar` is the proto object with property `count` and methods `stats`, `statfoo` and `statbar`.   Note that we factored out `stats` to avoid duplicating its code in each of `statfoo` and `statbar`.  (continued further down)

```
library(proto)

foobar <- proto(count = 0, 
          stats = function(., x) {
               .$count <- .$count + 1
               list(mean = mean(x), count = .$count)
          },
          statfoo = function(., x) c(.$stats(x), plus = 2),
          statbar = function(., x) c(.$stats(x), plus = 3)
)

foobar$statfoo(1:3)
foobar$statbar(2:4)
```

giving:

```
> foobar$statfoo(1:3)
$mean
[1] 2

$count
[1] 1

$plus
[1] 2

> foobar$statbar(2:4)
$mean
[1] 3

$count
[1] 2

$plus
[1] 3
```

**A second design** would be to have `statfoo` and `statbar` as independent functions and only keep `count` and `stats` in `foobar` (continued further down)

```
library(proto)

foobar <- proto(count = 0, 
          stats = function(., x) {
               .$count <- .$count + 1
               list(mean = mean(x), count = .$count)
          }
)

statfoo <- function(x) c(foobar$stats(x), plus = 2)
statbar <- function(x) c(foobar$stats(x), plus = 3)

statfoo(1:3)
statbar(2:4)
```

giving similar output to the prior example.

**Third approach** Of course the second variation could easily be implemented by using `local` and a function getting us close to where you started.  This does not use any packages but does not create a function only to throw it away:

```
foobar <- local({
            count <- 0
            function(x) {
               count <<- count + 1
               list(mean = mean(x), count = count)
            }
          })

statfoo <- function(x) c(foobar(x), plus = 2)
statbar <- function(x) c(foobar(x), plus = 3)

statfoo(1:3)
statbar(2:4)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use reference class like this:

```
foobar <- setRefClass(
    'foobar',
    fields = list(count='numeric'),
    methods = list(
        initialize=function() {
            .self$initFields(count = 0L)
        },
        statfoo = function(x) {
            count <<- count + 1L
            list(list(mean=mean(x), count=count), plus=2)
        },
        statbar = function(x){
            count <<- count + 1L
            list(list(mean=mean(x), count=count), minus=3)
        }
    )
)()

foobar$statfoo(5)
foobar$statbar(3)
```

It makes it relatively clear that neither `statfoo` nor `statbar` is a pure function.

Answer (score 4):

Another simple option is tocreate an environment and assign it to both functions.  Here I use simpler functions for illustrative purposes, but this can be easily extended:

```
f1 <- function() {count <<- count + 1; return(paste("hello", count))}
f2 <- function() {count <<- count + 1; return(paste("goodbye", count))}

environment(f1) <- environment(f2) <- list2env(list(count=0))
```

Then:

```
> f1()
[1] "hello 1"
> f2()
[1] "goodbye 2"
> f1()
[1] "hello 3"
```

Both functions have the same environment.