# Emulating static variable within R functions

Tags: r, static

I am looking for ways to emulate '[static](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable)' variables within R functions. (I know R is not a compiled language... hence the quotes.) With 'static' I mean that the 'static' variable should be persistent, associated to and modifiable from within the function.

My main idea is to use the `attr` function:

```
# f.r

f <- function() {
  # Initialize static variable.
  if (is.null(attr(f, 'static'))) attr(f, 'static') <<- 0L

  # Use and/or modify the static variable...
  attr(f, 'static') <<- attr(f, 'static') + 1L

  # return something...
  NULL
}
```

This works well, as long as `attr` can find `f`. In some scenario's this is no longer the case. E.g.:

```
sys.source('f.r', envir = (e <- new.env()))
environment(e$f) <- .GlobalEnv
e$f() # Error in e$f() : object 'f' not found
```

Ideally I would use `attr` on the 'pointer' of `f` from within `f`. `sys.function()` and `sys.call()` come to mind, but I do not know how to use these functions with `attr`.

Anyone ideas or better design patterns on how to emulate 'static' variables within R functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define `f` within a `local` like this:

```
f <- local({ 
  static <- 0
  function() { static <<- static + 1; static }
})
f()
## [1] 1
f()
## [1] 2
```

Comment: A functor pattern. So obvious. You are the best!

Answer (score 0):

```
rm(list=ls())`
cat("\014")  # ctrl+L`

# Function factory to produce a constant enclosing environment
f2 <- function() {
  # static / persistent list
  glbs <- list()
  glbs[["myvar"]] <- 0

  # function to be returned 
  function(vname = NULL, vvalue = NULL) {
    
    if(is.null(vvalue)){
      
      if(is.null(vname)){
        # print the list 
        print(glbs)
      }else{
        #  get value of vname variable from the list
        return(glbs[[vname]])  
      }
    } else {
      # update  value of vname
      glbs[[vname]] <<- vvalue
      return(vvalue)
    }
  }
  
}

> g2 <- f2()
> g2()
$myvar
[1] 0
> g2("myvar")
[1] 0
> g2("myvar", 1)
[1] 1
> g2()
$myvar
[1] 1
```

By modifying the internal function any necessary logic of working with static variable(s) could be introduced

Comment: This is exactly the same as the accepted answer. Why doublepost?